# How do I get my MonoTouch app deployed to device/app store now?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Over the last couple months I've been developing an app with the free version of MonoTouch.

Now (at the time of this question) it seems Novell killed it, and now that my app is ready, not really sure where to go. If I understand correctly, to deploy to device or package for app store, I need to get a license; do I buy one from Novell, or what? Should I just find a MonoTouch contractor that can take care of that part for me for now?

Hoping to get some wisdom from some seasoned MonoTouch folks on this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Novell Store](http://shop.novell.com/DRHM/store?Action=DisplayProductDetailsPage&SiteID=novell&Locale=en_US&Env=BASE&productID=163711300) is still up, and as recently as this weekend someone reported that the activation server is still working.

However, if you don't want to risk spending money on a license right now (and I don't blame you) your best bet is to get someone with an active MT license to help you.

Answer (score 0):

in order to submit an application to the appstore, you need to have an apple developer account (developer.apple.com), generate a .ipa file and submit it through your mac's application Loader/iTunes connect. More info here
(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html)

However, i am not sure but i think that in order to properly generate the .ipa file you need a MonoTouch license..

Answer (score 0):

Over the weekend Novell/Attachmate took down the Monotouch website database. This has killed the website. I don't think it will be back.

In the short term your best bet is to find another MonoTouch user and see if they will put your application up.

Now the database is down, I'm guessing the forums have gone. Someone setup a google group before this happened hopefully this will get some traction. http://groups.google.com/group/monotouch?hl=en-GB

Xamarin have announce that they shall be launching MonoTouch and MonoDroid compatible products in the next 3 months.
see [Xamarun's Website](http://www.xamarin.com/)